# why javascript splice called splice even though it doesn't join but splits the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

JavaScript splice method actually splits an array into two as shown in the below example:

```
var a = ['a','b','c'];
var b = a.splice(0,2);
console.log(a); // outputs ['c']
console.log(b); // outputs ['a'.'b']
```

Then why is it called splice since splice means to `join`

Comment: Your question says it's about "splice" but your sample code is "split"

Comment: `.splice` derives its name from the behavior of its [multi-argument form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), `splice(index, howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])` which "[splices in](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/splice)" the subsequent arguments into the array.

Comment: and why the down vote here.....was it dat silly a question??

Comment: @iJade I know this was an old question but I was confused with splice myself and just found the (possible) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine its named after RNA/DNA splicing where both addition and removal are called splicing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_splicing

The splice method in JavaScript can both add and remove, so yeah.

Comment: I think this was the wrong answer, it came from [perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice) but it was interesting to about RNA splicing

Answer (score 1):

Actually [JavaScript: the first 20 years](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3386327) said this

> 1.2 [Netscape 1997c]. Most of the library additions were inspired by features available in other popular languages. The Array concat and
> slice methods were inspired by Python’s sequence op- erations. The
> Array push, pop, shift, unshift, and **splice** were directly modeled on
> like-named Perl array functions.

[image: New Feature In JavaScript 1.2]

So it came from [perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice)